# How to show $\langle T(x),y\rangle=\langle x,S(y)\rangle$ for all $x, y$ implies, S is the adjoint operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T$ and $S$ are two functions from $H$ to $H$.
If
$$
\langle T(x),y\rangle=\langle x,S(y)\rangle
$$
for all $x, y \in H$, show that $T$ and $S$ are continuous linear operators with $S=T^*$. The last equality means that $S^*$ is adjoint(Hermitian) operator.

First we need two show $T$ and $S$ are linear operator but we do not have access to the expression representing them in terms of $x$. Also, we need to show they are bounded to conclude they are continuous.

**Note:** this is not $\mathbb{R}^n$, is a Hilbert space.

Comment: Hint for showing they are linear: For all $y$, 
$$\langle T(x_1+x_2),y\rangle = \langle x_1+x_2,S(y)\rangle  = \langle x_1,S(y)\rangle + \langle x_2,S(y)\rangle = \langle T(x_1),y\rangle + \langle T(x_2),y\rangle = \langle T(x_1)+T(x_2),y\rangle$$

Comment: Boundedness should follow by Closed Graph Thoerem: if $T(x_n) \to z$ and $x_n \to x$, after taking limit in your relation you have $\langle z, y \rangle = \langle x, S(y) \rangle= \langle T(x), y \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Closed Graph Theorem easily gives continuity of $T$ and $S$. By definition of $T^{*}$ we get $\langle x , T^{*}y \rangle =\langle x , Sy \rangle $ for all $x$ and $y$. Put $x=T^{*} y-Sy$ to see that $\|T^{*} y-Sy\|^{2}=0$ which gives $T^{*} y=Sy$ for all $y$.

Details for continuity: let $x_n \to x$ and $Tx_n \to z$. Then $\langle Tx_n , y \rangle =\langle x_n , Sy \rangle$ and letting $n \to \infty$ we get $\langle z , y \rangle =\langle x , Sy \rangle =\langle Tx , y \rangle$. This is true for all $y$ so $Tx=z$.

Comment: You still need to show $S$ and $T$ are continuous linear operators.

Comment: @Kabo Murphy: Can you elaborate on Closed Graph Theorem?

Comment: @Sepide I have added a proof.

Answer (score 0):

This theorem even holds more generally for operators in Banach spaces. See for example Proposition 2.3.11 in Analysis Now by Gert Pedersen.

Comment: You will find the proposition on page 60.

Comment: For the linearity you can follow the idea of kccu.

Comment: If you have this equation for every $y \in H$ the linearity follows as the scalar product is point separating.

Comment: Every Banach space is not a Hilbert space and we do not have an inner product.